# pseudo class :active not working on iframe of different domain

Tags: css, cross-domain

There's my codepen: https://codepen.io/fixiabis/pen/bGowerN (Note: There will be an error in the first preview, just modify the code to trigger a reload to fix it.)

Why pseudo class `:active` not working on iframe of different domain? and why `:hover` worked?

Expected Behavior: both iframe's opacity should be `1` on `:active`.